# TypeError: Undefined is not a constuctor (evaluating 'selectList.append(options)')

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs

I am getting this error when I run the test Cases (Jasmine): 
TypeError: Undefined is not a constuctor (evaluating 'selectList.append(options)')

I am not sure why a few of my test cases are failing because of this. The tests in my browser run absolutely fine but failing locally (Maven test). (Using Jasmine, Phantom JS).

Here I have an editUser button, which when clicked hides and (update and cancel) buttons pop up which are hidden until then.

```
function userEditUser(id) {
   var grandParent = $('#updateUser' + id).parent().parent().parent();
   var updateUser = $('#updateUser' + id);
   updateUser.siblings().removeClass('hideElement');
   updateUser.addClass('hideElement');
   var column_authority = document.getElementById('name1');
   var name_list = ["A", "B", "C"];
   var selectList = document.createElement('select');
   selectList.setAttribute('name', 'userName');
   for(var i = 0; i <name_list.length; i++){
       var options = document.createElement('option');
       options.text=name_list[i];
       selectList.append(options);
   }
  column_authority.appendChild(selectList);
```

One of the Test Cases that is failing:

```
 it('update button should not have a css class hideElement', function () {    
$('button[name="updateUser"]').click();
expect($('button[name="updateBtn"]')).not.toHaveClass('hideElement');
```

});

But it is failing at this point of the function:
selectList.append(options)

Comment: Since the code shown does not invoke any constructors, I presume the issue is somewhere at a higher level. You say you are using AngularJS, please show at least a self-contained Jasmine test that is failing.

Comment: What is `selectList`? Where is it initialized?

Comment: Take a look at the code now. Please ask if you want to know anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess Phantom JS does not recognize append function. Things are working fine for me now,

```
all I did is changed
selectList.append(options); to 
selectList.appendChild(options);
```

This change answered all my failing test cases. 
Thank you guys very much for your interest in providing a solution for my issue.